# In d3js, how can I add a tiny margin between bars in a group of a grouped column chart?

Tags: d3.js

I have a chart very similar to http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051, my question is how can I add a tiny margin between the values for each month, I assume it's decrease the rectangle width slightly and increase the x value slightly of the next bar.

```
 state.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) { return d.ages; })
.enter().append("rect")
  .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.name); })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
  .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });
```

so like on the width (x1.rangeBand() - 2) and on the x, (x1(d.name) + 2). I hope I'm making sense, I am pretty new to d3 but I think I'm getting the hang of it.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly how you can do it. Did you run into any issues when you tried that?

Comment: Yes that is indeed how I did it and it does work.Thanks.